# AngularJS ng-repeat on parent's scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use ng-repeat in child component, using a list that is defined is parent's component - in the controller. However the only way it works is when I specify that the list is coming from the parent

```
{$parent.list}
```

Is this the correct way to do that? Can I avoid it?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.component('parent', {
  restrict: 'E',
  controller: 'parentController',
  transclude: true,
  template: '<h1>List</h1><div ng-transclude></div>'
}).controller('parentController', function($scope) {
 $scope.list = ['one','two'];
});

myApp.component('child', {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    name: '<',
    list: '<'
  },
  template: '<h3>Child {{$ctrl.name}}</h3>'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <parent>
    <child list="list" ng-repeat="name in list" name="name"></child>
    <child list="list" ng-repeat="name in $parent.list" name="name"></child>
  </parent>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct way to do that?

Yes

> Can I avoid it?

Why? I don't see any problem to use `$parent` to get parent scope

---

If you want to get rid of `$parent`, you can move parent scope `parentController` to wrapper and `ng-repeat="name in list"` will work

```
<body ng-controller="parentController as vm">
   <parent >
     <pre>{{list}}</pre>
     <child list="list" ng-repeat="name in list" name="name"></child>
  </parent> 
</body>
```

So your component doesn't need controller:

```
myApp.component('parent', {
  restrict: 'E',
  //controller: 'parentController',
  transclude: true,
  template: '<h1>List</h1><div ng-transclude></div>'
})
```

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DDvqJfZ4rICi7sZmr59z?p=preview)